# Is there a way to load multiple .h5 model files as corresponding clients(tff.Clients) and run federated averaging?

Tags: tensorflow-federated

I am a beginner in federated learning using tff. I have a server and two remote clients. Using gRPC I have sent and received .h5 files with bidirectional byte streaming. I would like to load these two .h5 as two clients and run federated averaging on the weights. How do I do this ?

@tff.federated_computation(SERVER_MODEL_TYPE, CLIENT_DATA_TYPE)
def federated_eval(model, data):
return tff.federated_mean(
tff.federated_map(local_eval, [tff.federated_broadcast(model), data]))

Is there a way to implement federated computation on loaded weights ?

Comment: What you need seems like stateful clients. Does [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63498907/is-there-a-way-for-tff-clients-to-have-internal-states) help?

Comment: @JakubKonecny: At the moment I am defining MODEL_TYPE.weights as the type placement for tff.Clients and running it. It works.

`@tff.federated_computation(
  tff.FederatedType(MODEL_TYPE.weights,tff.CLIENTS)
  )  # new parameter for state
def run_fed_avg(client_states):
  average_update = tff.federated_mean(client_states)
  return average_update `