# Is there a way for TFF clients to have internal states without sending them to server? tf.function prevents updating internal states

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-federated

Similar to this [Is there a way for TFF clients to have internal states?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63498907/is-there-a-way-for-tff-clients-to-have-internal-states) question, but I dont want to send internal states to server. When I looked at the [stateful clients](https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/tree/master/tensorflow_federated/python/examples/stateful_clients) example we can see we had sent client states to server where they would eventually be the output of next_fn and get updated outside the entire tf.function/tff.tf_computation/tff.federated_computation structure

```
@tf.function
def client_update(model, dataset, client_state, server_message,
                  client_optimizer):
  """Performans client local training of `model` on `dataset`.
  Args:
    model: A `tff.learning.Model`.
    dataset: A 'tf.data.Dataset'.
    client_state: A 'ClientState'.
    server_message: A `BroadcastMessage` from server.
    client_optimizer: A `tf.keras.optimizers.Optimizer`.
  Returns:
    A 'ClientOutput`.
  """
  ...

  client_weight = tf.cast(num_examples, tf.float32)
  return ClientOutput(
      weights_delta, client_weight, loss_sum / client_weight,
      ClientState(
          client_index=client_state.client_index, iters_count=iters_count))


  @tff.federated_computation(federated_server_state_type,
                             federated_dataset_type,
                             federated_client_state_type)
  def run_one_round(server_state, federated_dataset, client_states):
    """Orchestration logic for one round of computation.
    Args:
      server_state: A `stateful_fedavg_tf.ServerState`.
      federated_dataset: A federated `tf.data.Dataset` with placement
        `tff.CLIENTS`.
      client_states: A federated `stateful_fedavg_tf.ClientState`.
    Returns:
      A tuple of updated `ServerState` and `tf.Tensor` of average loss.
    """
    ...

    return server_state, round_loss_metric, client_outputs.client_state
```

As far as I understand this is because `tf.function()` has some issues with [mutating class attributes of its inputs](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/function#depending_on_python_global_and_free_variables)

```
ValueError: func() should not modify its Python input arguments. Check if it modifies any lists or dicts passed as arguments. Modifying a copy is allowed.
```

Is there any way to workaround this so I can simply keep and update client states without doing federated aggregation.

Comment: Not really, TFF is a functional programming environment. But note that you don't need to do federated aggregation of client states, you can also return a value placed at tff.CLIENTS out of a tff.federated_copmutation.
Or, maybe I am misunderstanding your question?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What I meant by federated aggregation was simply sending the client states to server. from client_update to client_update_fn and then to run_one_round. we then update the client_states outside the tff structures. so we dont actually do any computations on these states in the server just "pass it through". federated aggregation might not be the right word for it.