# How to initialize clients' states in stateful Federated Learning, using the TensorFlow Federated framework?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-federated

I'm implementing the SCAFFOLD algorithm (https://arxiv.org/abs/1910.06378) in TensorFlow Federated, which needs stateful clients. I based my work on the answer to this [Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63498907/is-there-a-way-for-tff-clients-to-have-internal-states), but I cannot manage to correctly initialize the 'client_states'. For initializing them, I created the following function

```
@tff.federated_computation
def intialize_client_state():
    return tff.federated_value(server_init(), tff.CLIENTS)
```

, and call it right after iterative_process.initialize() (which initializes the server's weights). By doing this, I got the following error in the line where I call "initialize_client_state":

```
ValueError: Expected at least one participant for the 'CLIENTS' placement, found none. It is possible that the inferred number of clients is 0, you can explicitly pass `num_clients` when constructing the execution stack
```

What am I doing wrong ? How should I initialize the clients' states ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only execute that computation, the executor does not know what number of clients to expect, as the error hints at. You can set the number of clients by invoking [`tff.backends.native.set_local_execution_context`](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/api_docs/python/tff/backends/native/set_local_execution_context) with the `default_num_clients` you expect, somewhere at the start of your Python code.

Alternatively, if the initial client state is the same for all, you can create the state once, and have a list containing one copy of the state per client.